# Bottom bar with 'reusing layouts' vs 'viewflipper'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, menubar

Ok I'm working on an app has permanent bottom bar with buttons, each launch different activity on top of the bar (like Instagram app).

i'm searching around for solutions and looks like I may be able to use either 'viewflipper', 'reusing-layouts' or 'actionbar'. I do not want to use 'actionbar' so that's out of the picture.

so 'reusing layouts' vs 'viewflipper' - which is better in term of performance, memory cost and effective presentation (the bar not refresh/reload every activity change)? Or do you have a better suggestion of solution?

*reference:

viewflipper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html 

reusing layout: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok I'm working on an app has permanent bottom bar with buttons, each
>   launch different activity on top of the bar (like Instagram app).

I'm not familiar with the Instagram app but how does it launch different activities on top of the bar? I think you are referring to different "content" appearing in the *same* `Activity` when clicking the buttons.

> so 'reusing layouts' vs 'viewflipper' - which is better in term of
>   performance, memory cost and effective presentation (the bar not
>   refresh/reload every activity change)?

Both versions will handle the bar remaining on content change(as you'll have a single `Activity`), so this isn't an issue.

Reusing layouts will probably be better on memory as you only have a single layout file in memory at one time. Unfortunately it will be much harder to work with the layouts as you'll need to reinitialize the views from those layouts each time a new one appears (and it will be much harder to do it if the layouts are really different from each other).

The `ViewFlipper` will hold its child views in it so if you have a big amount of screens to show it will not go well with the memory. You could probably create a system to remove child views from the `ViewFlipper` that aren't currently visible but I would not mess with that.

> Or do you have a better suggestion of solution?

**Fragments**. Reusable components, much easier to handle, assistance from the framework(as long as you don't go against it) with managing them, easier to handle various screen layouts...

Comment: hmm can a single activity display different contents with different layouts/views (such as gridview, framelayout,...)? I thought 'reusing layouts' can be use in more than one activity.

Comment: @jerrytouille You can reuse layouts across activities with no problems, the problem is that if you use different activities and you include the buttons bar in each of those activities the user will see the bar refreshing when a new activity is started. I thought you wanted the user to not see this kind of behavior. And yes, you can use different layouts in a single `Activity` you can basically call `setContentView` with a new layout at what moment you want and how many times you want.

Comment: i was doing some readings on 'Fragments' since i'm new to this, so based on your suggestion: let say we have a _DashboardActivity_ with 4 buttons in the bottom bar, each btn will launch different fragment? And a fragment is like a mini-activity, with its own components, that can be added, removed in a single 'dashboard/main' activity; thus fragment is not just a layout/view that we use in 'reusing layouts'.

Comment: ...continue: A prime example is the Camera intent, which can be a fragment. In instagram the photo app, a button on the dashboard allow user to take picture, while another button launch another fragment to show the photo gallery in GridView, etc. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @jerrytouille Yes, each button will add a fragment(which isn't just a view container it's a view container or/and behavior). Looking at the images from Google Play for Instagram, the login screen an map screen are different activities, the screen with the 5 buttons it's probably just a single activity, the filters screen it's also most likely just a single screen. I can't say anything about the camera screen as I don't use the app.